# Mocked method returns actual value instead of the mocked one

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito

I've been asked to set up continuous integration on Android Studio so I started with unit testing and mocking.

I feel I missunderstood the Mockito basis and working. I've found this kind of examples on the Internet:

```
    @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
    public class ExampleUnitTest {

      MainActivity classToTest = new MainActivity();

      @Mock
      ClassIDontWantToTest classToMock;

      /**
       * Examples found a lot of times on the Internet
       * My method is not tested at all
       * I think it doesn't make sense to test Mockito but our own methods
       * @throws Exception
       */
      @Test
      public void testMethodIDontWantToTest() throws Exception {
        when(classToMock.methodIDontWantToTest()).thenReturn("Mocked result");
        assertTrue(classToMock.methodIDontWantToTest().equals("Mocked result"));
      }

    }
```

This is my code:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
      ClassIDontWantToTest classIWantToMock = new ClassIDontWantToTest();

      /**
       * Actual Method I want to test
       * @return Return value
       */
      public String methodIWantToTestButReturnsUnspectedValue() {

          //  (...) Code to test

          return classIWantToMock.methodIDontWantToTest();
      }
    }


    public class ClassIDontWantToTest {

      public String methodIDontWantToTest() {
        return "Actual result";
      }

    }
```

And this is how I understand it would have to be done:

```
    @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
    public class ExampleUnitTest {
      MainActivity classToTest = new MainActivity();

      @Mock
      ClassIDontWantToTest classToMock;

      /**
       * Test I want to do and I think it makes sense, but it doesn't work
       * @throws Exception
       */
      @Test
      public void testMethodIWantToTest() throws Exception {
        when(classToMock.methodIDontWantToTest()).thenReturn("Mocked result");
        assertTrue(classToTest.methodIWantToTestButReturnsUnspectedValue().equals("Mocked result"));
      }
    }
```

Obviously there's something I don't understand, but I don't know what it is.
May anybody please tell me where I'm wrong?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Is this a unit test (in a JVM) or an instrumentation test (in an emulator)? Also, both `ClassIDontWantToTest` and `methodIDontWantToTest` are public and non-final, right?

Comment: As far as I can see, you haven't injected your mock object into the class you're testing.  My preferred way to approach this is to add a second constructor to the class you want to test, where you pass in the value for `classIWantToMock` - then test an object that has been instantiated with this second constructor.  If you can't add a second constructor to the class, then another approach is to put the @InjectMocks annotation  on the declaration of `classToTest` in the test - but that can sometimes be flakier.

Answer (score 0):

Your mock object is not setup correctly, means your  `MainActivity classToTest = new MainActivity();` class is not injected with  `ClassIDontWantToTest classToMock;`

to do that you need something like this:

```
 @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
 public class ExampleUnitTest {

  @InjectMocks
  MainActivity classToTest;

  @Before
  public void setup() {
   MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
  }

  @Mock
  ClassIDontWantToTest classToMock;

  @Test
  public void testMethodIWantToTest() throws Exception {
   when(classToMock.methodIDontWantToTest()).thenReturn("Mocked result");
   String expected = classToTest.methodIWantToTestButReturnsUnspectedValue();
   assertEquals(expected, "Mocked result");
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Eureka!
  As David Wallace said, I had to put `@InjectMocks` annotation on the declaration of `classToTest`.

Now my test works fine, and it makes sense. Thank you very much!

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ExampleUnitTest {

  @Mock
  ClassIDontWantToTest classToMock;

  @InjectMocks
  MainActivity classToTest;

  ////////// Test that makes sense and works fine
  @Test
  public void testMethodIWantToTest() throws Exception {
    when(classToMock.methodIDontWantToTest()).thenReturn("Mocked result");
    assertTrue(classToTest.methodIWantToTest().equals("Mocked result"));
  }

}



////////////////  Class to mock
public class ClassIDontWantToTest {
  public String methodIDontWantToTest() {
    return "Actual result";
  }
}




////////////// Class to be tested
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  ClassIDontWantToTest classIWantToMock = new ClassIDontWantToTest();

  ////////////  Actual Method I want to test
  public String methodIWantToTest() {
      //  (...) Code to test
      return classIWantToMock.methodIDontWantToTest();
  }

}
```

Comment: Then you should mark this answer as "accepted" (or kuhajeyan's one, which is basically the same).